# What is mean pipe operator between 2 int variants?

Tags: c++

Having the follow code -

```
    enum FileOpenFlags {
    flagREAD = 1, flagWRITE = 2,
    flagCREATE = 4, flagEND = 8,
    flagAPPEND = flagWRITE | flagEND,
    };
    cout << flagAPPEND << endl;
```

gives `10` . can you explain me what the `|` did ?

Comment: Yes, I can. But I won't as you should have read a C(++) tutorial instead of bugging me with this.

Comment: Those `flag` prefixes can be easily avoided with scoped enums in C++11.

Comment: @H2CO3 all my google searches gave results about another meaning of "pipe" , sorry about bugging you  .

Comment: That's because it's not a pipe. It's an inclusive or operator.

Comment: @PeteBecker, but some will know it as a pipe *character*. I can easily see where the confusion comes from, and I'm glad to have a place on StackOverflow for Google to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It did a [bitwise `or`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_OR#OR) of the two values.

Answer (score 4):

`flagWRITE`'s (2) binary representation is 0010

`flagEND`'s (8) binary representation is 1000

0010 OR 1000 gives you 1010 which equals 10

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_OR#OR)........

Answer (score 2):

It's a bitwise "OR" operator. So the bit value of 2 and 8 respectively get OR'd bitwise.

So:

```
   1000 (flagEND = 8) 
OR 0010 (flagWRITE = 2)
-----------
 = 1010 (flagAppend = 10)
```